# PHP PDO insertion in fields with blank spaces not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

I'm a bit confused about this, I think the problem is inserting data in fields with blank spaces, what's the right way to do this?

The error msg I'm getting is:

DB ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

```
 $consulta = "INSERT INTO $table 
        (Title, Title_Short, City, `Department / Branch`)
        VALUES (:Title, :Title_Short, :City, :`Department / Branch`)";

        $result = $db->prepare($consulta);

    $result->execute(array(
        ":Title" => getTitle($url_job),
        ":Title_Short" => getTitle_Short($url_job),
        ":City" => getTitle($url_job),
        ":Department / Branch" => getTitle_Short($url_job),

        ));
```

Comment: You simply cannot use backticks or spaces in a placeholder name.

Comment: placeholder names do **NOT** have to match the name of the field you're inserting to. THat's just insane... `:foo` would do just as well.

Comment: is there any way to make the insertion using fields with spaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters aren't allowed in placeholders. Use:

```
$consulta = "INSERT INTO $table 
    (Title, Title_Short, City, `Department / Branch`)
    VALUES (:Title, :Title_Short, :City, :DeptBranch)";

$result = $db->prepare($consulta);

$result->execute(array(
    ":Title" => getTitle($url_job),
    ":Title_Short" => getTitle_Short($url_job),
    ":City" => getTitle($url_job),
    ":DeptBranch" => getTitle_Short($url_job),

));
```